# Veins V2V only without RSU

Tags: omnet++, veins

Which of the Veins version uses vehicle to vehicle communication (car) only without RSU. The current veins uses RSU, any way to remove RSU and use V2V (CAR) only.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

How to add and remove modules from a simulation is documented in the user manual and the topic of lesson one in the tic toc tutorial. From a quick look at the top level .ned file of the simulation you should also see the line where the RSU is instantiated. Simply delete this line.